# NetBeans database

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans

Today in class we made a simple Java program that manipulates through database, reading from it, writing to it and saving data on a .txt file. More or less, I understood the code.

The problem is, in order to work with databases, we did a bunch in NetBeans of stuff I can't quite recall at the moment, but we imported 3 .jar files named Derby or something. Problem is, I don't have that stuff here and I don't know what to look for. All I wanted was to extend the program's capabilities so that it can search through database. Can anyone point me to the right direction? What do I need?

Comment: http://db.apache.org/derby/ if you want to use Derby.

Answer (score 2):

[Netbeans.org](http://www.netbeans.org) is very good source of Java tutorials. The one you need is [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html and if you are writing a desktop client for the DB, maybe this could help too: http://netbeans.org/kb/70/java/gui-db.html

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are after Apache Derby http://db.apache.org/derby/

jQuery.jar

A database, such as MySQL, installed on your PC.

Based on my experience with Netbeans you can connect to a database using the services tab. You can then use jQuery to create a connection, query and statement with the selected database using java.

I hope that answers your question. If it doesn't take a look at https://netbeans.org/. Netbeans have a lot of very useful tutorials.

Comment: jQuery is a **JavaScript** library. You can't use that to connect to a database using JDBC

Comment: Oh good point. I got confused as I'm currently using Java and JS to talk to a database. Goodjob pointing that out.